# When I use last-child and first-child there is a problem of inconsistent format, I don't know why?

Tags: html, css

When I view it in the browser, I find that the graphics of `div1` are obviously larger than `div2`. If I change the css style of `div2`, I will find that `div:last-child{}` has no effect. I don't know what's going on, can someone help me?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}

div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

div:last-child {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
```

This is the screenshot:

[image: Example of different size divs]

Comment: _"If I change the css style of div2, I will find that div:last-child{} has no effect"_ - then it probably isn't actually the last child of its parent. Use your browser dev tools, to inspect what DOM structure you actually have ... Browser extensions for example often insert their own scripts at the end of body.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2gq4wnvr/ shows the same issue - because jsfiddle itself inserts a script element at the end of body. If you wrap them both in a `section` - which jsfiddle will not insert additional elements into - it looks as expected, https://jsfiddle.net/2gq4wnvr/1/

Comment: Yes, div2 is indeed not the last tag, because I use the Live Server extension, the last element is the script tag

Comment: Need to use last-of-type, see Rounin's answer, `div:last-child` will target the last child element but not necessarily a div

Answer (score 0):

It isn't uncommon to see unintended / unexpected results with:

- `:first-child`
- `:last-child`
- `:nth-child()`
- `:nth-last-child()`

if the pseudo-class selector the CSS architect requires is actually one of:

- `:first-of-type`
- `:last-of-type`
- `:nth-of-type()`
- `:nth-last-of-type()`

---

If you explicitly want to select the last `<div>` of a parent element, the correct selector is:

```
div:last-of-type
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use items selectively like last-first:child, you must first set a reference.

```css
    * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .box {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: pink;
        }
.container div:first-child {   
            background-color: red;       
            padding: 10px;
        }
 .container  div:last-child {
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
</div>
```